# Parser Error Problem

Tags: asp.net

Hi I have found a problem in Multilingual Asp.Net Web Application

I have Created a Global.asax file and write the code

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] languages = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages;

    if (languages[0].ToLower() != null && languages[0].ToLower()!="")
    {

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(languages[0].ToLower());

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(languages[0].ToLower());

    }
}
```

and define Label Like this

```
   <asp:Label ID="Labeldg" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, Labeldg %>"</asp:Label>
```

But it through Parser error like:

> Parser Error 
>   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The resource object with key 'LblUsrName_Login' was not found.
>   Source Error:
>
> `</div>`
>
> `<div class="impcLoginText_Login">`
>
> `<asp:Label ID="LblUsrName" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:PageResource,  LblUsrName_Login %>" "></asp:Label>`

Comment: Am I reading this wrong?  Are you saying you tried putting a label in your global.asax?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I' reading this wrong, it looks to me like you're trying to put a label in the global.asax.  The global.asax does not have a visible user interface, so you can't put a label in it.

Answer (score 0):

The Tag is specifying that the string resides in PageResource  which should be a resx file within the App_GlobalResources folder.  If its not there then its not found and you get the error you are seeing here.

Either add the resx file and put in the correct entry or alter the tag to read from an existing resx file.

Comment: Im assuming you are not putting the label in the global.asax file as that is just crazy ;)